# How to improve build times for Polymer 3.0

Tags: polymer-3.x

We are currently developing a web application based on polymer. Our app consists of about 250 custom elements. Up to Polymer 2 build times using vulcanizer where really fast, not more than some minutes. We migrated the whole project to Polymer 3, and now the bundled build takes about 40 minutes. If we do an unbundled build it will quite be as fast as Polymer 2. Unfortunately "polymer build" isn't really helpful with verbose information about what is going on... Any idea?

Tried already excluding all folders containing not needed files

We need to get build times faster for frequent releases

Comment: Eventually we switched to rollup. From 3 hours we got down to 5 minutes.

Comment: Hey Matthias, how did you switch to Rollup? I'm currently having issues when bundling the fragments since they will not dedupe the core libraries and custom elements such as dom-module for instance.

Comment: @AndréSilva, we use rollup with @rollup/plugin-commonjs, @rollup/plugin-node-resolve and rollup-plugin-terser instead of polymer build. The rest is pretty much standard rollup configuration.